# The formula for "Two-for" price is 20% off the total price of two items. Prompt the user for each of the values and calculate the result

Tags: python

The following is what the output should look like:

Enter price 1: 10.0

Enter price 2: 20.0

The 'two-for' price is $24.0

The code I entered is:

```
price_one = float(input('Enter price 1: '))

print(price_one)

price_two = float(input('Enter price 2: '))

print(price_two)

two_for_price = (price_one + price_two)-((price_one + price_two)*(20/100))

print("The 'two-for' price is $",two_for_price)
```

(The inputs are 10.0 and 20.0 respectively.)

But the output I am getting is:

```
Enter price 1: 10.0

Enter price 2: 20.0

The 'two-for' price is $ 24.0
```

In the last line I need:

```
The 'two-for' price is $24.0
```

Please help me out!!

Comment: look up string.format()

Comment: no need to be mean he is clearly trying ... the answer is to use string formatting `print("The 'two-for' price is $%0.2f"%two_for_price)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your underlying problem is that the `print` function behavior, given a list of items, is to print each item, separated by a space.  This is often convenient for quick-and-dirty print-outs, but you want something more refined.

What you need to do is create a string with the proper spacing and then print that string out.

So you could do this:

```
print("The 'two-for' price is $" + str(two_for_price) + ".")
```

The problems are (a) that's kind of clumsy and unreadable and (b) it does not format properly, it's "$2.6" instead of "$2.60".

You can use either of two formatting mechanisms offered by Python, either explicit, like this:

```
print("The 'two-for' price is ${0}".format(two_for_price))
```

or implicit, like this

```
print("The 'two-for' price is $%f" % two_for_price)
```

Both of them look a little better, but the formatting errors are the same and worse ("$2.600000"!) respectively.  Fortunately, both offer nice customizable formatting:

```
print("The 'two-for' price is ${0:.2f}".format(two_for_price))
```

and

```
print("The 'two-for' price is $%0.2f" % two_for_price)
```

Both of which look reasonably clean and display perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

If i'm reading this correctly you just need to remove a space from your output.

Change your last line to this:

`print("The 'two-for' price is ${0}".format(two_for_price))`